# How to host a file using SCP on Linux without root privilege

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I am a user on a Linux server. I want to host a file on the server by starting an SCP server, similar to starting an HTTP server over a custom port. e.g. "python -m SimpleHTTPServer". I want to use arbitrary user credential on the spot. e.g. user1/password123

I do not want to involve root privilege. How do I do that?

e.g.:

```
my-scp-server -p 2222 -U user1 -P password123 -d /tmp
```

Comment: Why not just do `scp username@remote:/path/to/remotefile /path/to/localfile`?

Comment: I want to host file(s), not copy file as a client. The real clients may not be capable or allowed to become an SSH/SCP server.

Comment: Then SCP is not the answer. You could use Samba network shares or FTP server. Samba is probably simpler to implement.

Answer (score 1):

While the long term (stable) solution is Samba/FTP/NFS (but they requires `root` access), if you need to set up a temporary server you may launch `sshd` with proper options and config file. In particular, you can use `sshd -f ~/.ssh/sshd_config` where `~/.ssh/sshd_config` is a valid OpenSSHd configuration file.

As you're starting `sshd` as user, or at least for SCP only, you might need these configuration in `sshd_config`:

- `UsePrivilegeSeparation no` to avoid `setuid` and `setgid` calls
- `UsePam no` to avoid using PAM
- `Port 2022` to configure a custom port
- `HostKey` pointing to an host key
- `PidFile` pointing to a pid file created while `sshd` is running

Use `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` as a template, it should contains also comments for help.

Then you can force SFTP (see help for `ForceCommand internal-sftp`) or, if you really need SCP, you can use `rssh` shell (http://pizzashack.org/rssh/) to force SCP-only sessions.

**Be aware that, with this configuration, all files can be accessed remotely** (under the privilege of the user running `sshd` process). If you need to restrict access to some files you should create/configure a *chroot* using `ChrootDirectory` in `sshd_config`, or `chrootpath` in `rssh` configuration, and add the `CAP_SYS_CHROOT` capability to `sshd` executable (the `CAP_SYS_CHROOT` capability is needed for `chroot` syscall as user - if you don't want to execute `sshd` as `root`).

Some refs:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/344295/is-it-possible-to-run-sshd-as-a-normal-user
- https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-04/msg00363.html
- https://serverfault.com/questions/83856/allow-scp-but-not-actual-login-using-ssh

Comment: Using the appropriate options (eg. `ChrootDirectory` in `sshd_config` or `chrootpath` in `rssh` config) actions can be restricted to a specific directory.

Comment: I've added a section for chroot/capabilities

Comment: I managed to start sshd but after I login, I get disconnected before I see anything. Also, ultimately, I want to use a custom credential (e.g. user1/password123) instead of exposing my own credentials. Much like anonymous ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. I got the tips from one of the links in Enrico's answer. Specifically, using dropbear: https://serverfault.com/a/911709

What I did was I downloaded the dropbear source code and built it myself. I don't see an option to specify my own credentials. So I decided to make a proof of concept change by modifying the source `svr-authpasswd.c` function `svr_auth_password()` and added the following line:

```
    unsigned int changepw;

  + send_msg_userauth_success();

    /* check if client wants to change password */
```

This allows me to login with any password. I can also scp. It is not ideal in the sense that I cannot limit the sshd in a jailed environment and I also don't want to give shell access to client. But for a proof of concept, it works.